# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr') paypal plus Brazil

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, shopware

I am trying to integrate Paypal plus for Brazil(Sandbox) based on the following documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/br/payment-selection-page/

I am getting the error from https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js file

> ppplusdcc.js:formatted:5349 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'substr')
> at Function.Q [as doCheckout] (ppplusdcc.js:formatted:5349:25)
> at SwagPayPalPlusPaymentWall.afterPayOrder (payment-wall.js?27e3:300:1)
> at XMLHttpRequest.eval (http-client.service.js?93cb:133:1)

The cookie name inside the file is paypalplus_session

If we print the cookie we get the following values

> collectBillingAddress: false
> country: "BW"
> disallowRememberedCards: false
> ecToken: "EC-87B846367D652562M"
> language: "en_GB"
> mode: "sandbox"
> payerEmail: "sb-60hxz13832490@personal.example.com"
> payerFirstName: "John"
> payerLastName: "Doe"
> payerPhone:"0634312345"
> payerTaxId: ""
> payerTaxIdType: ""
> rememberedCards: ""
> thirdPartyMethods: {}
> useraction: "commit"
> [[Prototype]]: Object

'paymentMethod' variable is accessed from the cookie in ppplusdcc.min.js file. but it actually does not exist in the cookie.

Does anybody know why the 'paymentMethod' variable is not set in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create [a sandbox Business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) of country: Brazil.
2. Create [a REST App](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) for that Brazil account.
3. Change your integration to use that App's client-id and secret for all API calls.

Comment: Same error again

Comment: Update your question with the current error, and also with everything about how you are invoking the JS . Such code should use hardcoded values, not any variables that can't be seen

Comment: Hi @Preston PHX

Thank you for helping me

I have created a test. you can find the files here. can you please check this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gyxhaE1HGY8gPyi5QlmCbay1A1kqxkGC/view?usp=sharing

I have uploaded the test files to 
https://shopwaredemo.thebuild.site/paypal-plus/paypalPlus.php
but it is showing as forbidden.